# preventing sensitive data exposure using combination of AES and 3DES algorithms

Tags: algorithm, web, cryptography, aes, 3des

I wanted to use a combination of AES and 3DES algorithms to prevent sensitive data exposure in web site and web applications.

I want to know is it a good combination and will it be effective and also which technologies can I use to implement it practically.

Comment: Why do you think you need more than just AES?

Comment: I started working on my dissertation and selected that topic

Comment: I wanted to highly secure the sensitive data in server-side using the combination of these two algorithms.

Comment: I need your guidance regarding my topic. or if I can go to any other good topic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What are your goals?

There really should be no reason to use 3DES in any modern application.

What mode of AES can you use, is AES-GCM ok?

In a web application I would limit my solution to using Web Crypto supported algorithms and modes.

See:
https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples/blob/master/README.md#aes-gcm

Comment: I started working on my dissertation and selected that topic.

Comment: I wanted to highly secure the sensitive data in server-side using the combination of these two algorithms.

Comment: I need your guidance regarding my topic. or if I can go to any other good topic. Thanks

Comment: In 2020 it makes no sense to use 3DES for anything other than interop with an existing system. I think if I was doing a dissertation on crypto in web applications I would be focused on how to do so securely and explore the weaknesses the solution would have.